Run Server Error : getting [errono: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'open'] for "npm run dev"
I want to run a local server.
When I created a new next-app project and ran local server with npm run dev, it worked.
But after there are some changes, I got this error for npm run dev
So I removed the folder .next, and npm run build and try running server again.
It worked at first, but I got the same error after refreshing.
Error:
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: \Homepage_client_ver2.0\\.next\\static\\chunks\\app\\layout.js'
}

//package.json
{
  "name": "homepage_client_ver2.0",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/third-parties": "^14.2.4",
    "next": "^14.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.14.1",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^18.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2"
  }
}

Things I tried:

remove 'node_modules' folder, '.next' folder -> install -> run server (for removing cache)
'npm run build' -> run server (it was effective for a while)
change the path to remove Korean characters (I think it might be a reason for error but it wasn't)
remove my local repository, and clone again (to ensure that no.1 is done correctly again)
reset the OS as the error seemed causing in the 'system call'


turn off or add next directory to exception list of antivirus.
or turn off Riot Vanguard
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/60185#discussioncomment-9145585

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

It's surprising that Riot Vanguard may do such thing. Probably it's really antivirus activity
